# Getting Error while querying Account list -sosl -salesforce

Tags: query, sosl

I am getting error while querying Account & cusst obj Customer ,Below is my error and query.

Error :"Line: 9, Column: 29
Incompatible types since an instance of `List<SObject>` is never an instance of `List<Account>`"

```
List<List<SObject>> custAcctSearchList=new List<List<SObject>>();
//SOSL query which will search for Text 'ABC'string in Customer & Account
//object fields
custAcctSearchList=[FIND 'ABC*' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Apex_Customer__c(Id,Apex_Customer__c.Name,
                     Apex_Customer__c.Apex_Customer_Description__c),Account(Id,Name)];    

system.debug('Result for Acct & cust '+custAcctSearchList);
Apex_Customer__c[] searchedCustomer =((List<Apex_Customer__c>)custAcctSearchList[0]);
Account[] searchedAccount =((List<Account>)custAcctSearchList[1]);

system.debug('Result of Customer List '+searchedCustomer);
system.debug('Result of Customer List '+searchedAccount);
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Can you share the complete error message that you are getting. Basically the name of the sobject for both the lists.

Comment: what I posted is entire  error msg . sObject name- Apex_Customer__c & other  is Account(standard obj)

Comment: do you have a class named `Account` declared somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No ! I have  not defined any class named Account